# Change the size and position of an Iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

I want to change the size an position of an Iframe from youtube, (i have 3 embeded iframes inside a container div?, so when someone clics on the iframe it grows and apears in the center of the screen.

What's the best way to do so?????

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer. Please paste here the code you have right now.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, you could add a javascript addEventListener that adds padding and margins the iframe to the center so that it acts like youtube's fullscreen algorithm